# Ruby's Object#define_method vs Module#define_method

Tags: ruby

Can anyone elaborate on the differences between ruby's `Object#define_method` and `Module#define_method` and where they are generally used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object#define_method` does not exist:

```
o = Object.new
o.define_method
#NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for #<Object:0x1448a80>
```

However, `Object.define_method` exists:

```
Object.define_method
#NoMethodError: private method `define_method' called for Object:Class
```

That's because `Object` is an object of class `Class`, and `Class` is a subclass of `Module`:

```
Object.class # => Class
Class.ancestors # => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So when you call `Object.define_method`, you're calling `Module#define_method`.

Just remember that classes are objects of class `Class`, and it'll be as clear as mud!

Comment: Thanks Andrew, very well explained!. I tried your suggestion in IRB and its clear now.
`pry(main)> Class.ancestors
=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`
`pry(main)> Object.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Answer (score 5):

`Object#define_method` is actually `Module#define_method`.

```
pry(main)> Object.method(:define_method).owner
=> Module
pry(main)> Module.method(:define_method).owner
=> Module
```

Comment: Thanks Dogbert. But Object is the superclass of Module so how the #define_method defined in Module available to the Object class as a class method? Had it been defined in Object class then Module would have inherited it and not the other way round, right?

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure either. However, I think fundamental types such `Module`, `Class` and of course `Object` are implemented directly within the interpreter. Therefore these are not constraint by the usual ruby semantics. I realize, this is kind of a non-explanation. I'd love to learn more about the subject as well. Anyone?